# Curl of Deviatoric Stress Tensor In Index Notation

Tags: tensors

I'm taking the curl of the deviatoric stress tensor in index notation, and I've ran across something that I can't seem to be able to simplify. The issue is shown in the following portion of the curl operation:

[image]

The first two terms on the right hand side should be zero because the curl of a scalar and the curl of a gradient of a scalar are zero. The last term will then be given by:

[image]

Since U has a subscript m on that last term on the RHS, then I can't just define it as the gradient of the vorticity like I did on the first term on the RHS. Is there any further way to simplify it or does that just have to be the curl of the gradient of velocity?

Comment: After expanding the term, it's obvious that the last term is simply zero.